# If this capital letter F is acceptable or not

Tags: writing, capitalization, early-modern-english, letter-writing

Is the F in the picture an acceptable capital letter? As the length of the lower horizontal line equals to the upper horizontal line.

This is not a font question. That’s a very basic question or a rule of a unit of a language - letter in English. It’s very clear for a foreigner to distinguish whether it’s essential to learn it correctly from the very first beginning.

[image]

Comment: You should ask "Is the F in the picture an acceptable capital letter?" Yes, of course; it's usual to have the two horizontals of equal length.

Comment: In typography the lower horizontal stroke of a capital F is more often a bit shorter than the upper stroke. But this is a stylistic choice made at the discretion of the designer of the typeface.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about font design, and not the English language.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum you could even make the lower stroke longer if you wanted to.

Comment: There could be a [languagelearning.se] question about which typefaces are suitable for young learners.  This particular typeface is a very geometric sans font, and uses perfect circles and lines of equal length/width

Comment: What is your doubt here?  What would be more convincing than an actual printed example of a letter F with two equal length horizontal lines?  Especially one printed from a source that is explicitly about learning how to form the letters.  If this is not a font question, it is trivial.  Yes, look at the letter F in the picture.

Comment: Teaching an alphabet must include being flexible about the exact way a letter looks. Saying this is not a font question does not make it so. Since the worksheet answer must be **f**, so there is no problem. And your question opens with a similar F: "Is the F in the picture..."

Comment: I just wanted to make sure this F is acceptable in general English understandings. Even when it is appeared in the legal writings or any other formal uses.

Comment: Please unclose this question.

Answer (score 2):

The form of our letter F is based on the Phonecian symbol waw, a vertical line forking at the top like Y, which was appropriated by the Greeks into the characters "digamma" and "Upsilon". Digamma (which represented the numeral 6) is just an F with equal horizontals and a lip on the bottom one.

So yes, it's fine.

Comment: So that’s a very proper answer about the origin of a letter forming.  And it’s not a question about font.